Как в Godot сделать так, чтобы при наводки камеры игрока от первого лица на 3д модель при нажатии что то происходило?
Я делаю 3д игру на Годоте от 1 лица, игрок спавнится в своей комнате без возможности выйти, рядом с ним есть компьютер. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы когда камера была наведена на компьютер, чтобы игрок был не слишком далеко от компа и игрок нажал мышкой, изображение на мониторе поменялось (на включение компа). Вопрос - как такое сделать?

Вы можете использовать Raycast3d
